# React/Redux not rendering nextState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, rendering

The common cause for my issue when researching this is mutating the state and not returning a new object of the state which causes redux to not recognize a change. However, this is not and has never been an issue and i'm well aware of it. I'm returning a new object. In the logger which you can see in the attached image it displays the successful api call resolved and the nextState is updated but never rendered. Refreshing the page acts exactly the same even though i expected to possibly need to do so upon initial landing to root page.

Component:

```
import pokemonReducer from '../../reducers/pokemon_reducer';
import PokemonIndexItem from './pokemon_index_item';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import PokemonDetailContainer from './pokemon_detail_container';


class PokemonIndex extends React.Component {
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.requestAllPokemon();
    }

    render() {
        const pokemon = this.props.pokemon;
        
       

        return (
            <section className="pokedex">
                <Route path='/pokemon/:pokemonID' component={PokemonDetailContainer} />
                <ul>{pokemon && pokemon.map(poke => <li>{poke.name}{poke.id}</li>)}</ul>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default PokemonIndex;
```

and the container:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { selectAllPokemon } from '../../reducers/selectors';
import PokemonIndex from './pokemon_index';
import { requestAllPokemon } from '../../actions/pokemon_actions';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    pokemon: selectAllPokemon(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    requestAllPokemon: () => dispatch(requestAllPokemon())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PokemonIndex);
```

the reducer:

```
import { RECEIVE_ALL_POKEMON, RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON} from '../actions/pokemon_actions';



const pokemonReducer = (initialState = {}, action) => {
    Object.freeze(initialState);
    switch(action.type) {
        
        case RECEIVE_ALL_POKEMON:
            return Object.assign({}, initialState, action.pokemon);
        case RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON:
            let poke = action.payload.pokemon
            return Object.assign({}, initialState, {[poke.id]: poke})
        default: 
            return initialState;
    }
};

export default pokemonReducer;
```

secondary reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import pokemonReducer from './pokemon_reducer'


const entitiesReducer = combineReducers({
    pokemon: pokemonReducer,
});

export default entitiesReducer;
```

rootreducer:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import entitiesReducer from './entities_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    entities: entitiesReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

as requested here is the selectors defined in reducers folder

```
export const selectAllPokemon = (state) => {
    Object.values(state.entities.pokemon);
};

export const selectSinglePokemon = (state) => {
    Object.values(state.entities.pokemon)
};
```

and here is the actions created:

```
export const RECEIVE_ALL_POKEMON = "RECEIVE_ALL_POKEMON";
export const RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON = "RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON";
import * as APIUtil from '../util/api_util';

export const receiveAllPokemon = (pokemon) => (
    {
        type: RECEIVE_ALL_POKEMON,
        pokemon
    }
);

export const requestAllPokemon = () => (dispatch) => {
    APIUtil.fetchAllPokemon()
        .then(
            pokemon => 
            { dispatch(receiveAllPokemon(pokemon));}
        );
        
};

export const receiveSinglePokemon = data => (
    {
        type: RECEIVE_SINGLE_POKEMON,
        data
    }
);

export const requestSinglePokemon = id => (dispatch) => {
    APIUtil.fetchSinglePokemon(id)
        .then(pokemon => {dispatch(receiveSinglePokemon(pokemon));
        return pokemon;});
};
```

[nextstate showing in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVoDc.png)

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ pokemon: selectAllPokemon(state) });`, can you show me this selectAllPokemon selector?

Comment: Also provide the code where you define your actions and your initialState above the pokemonReducer.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. It's got me questioning how well i understand react-redux. I've updated post with requested code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in your question, your redux state is getting properly set but your new state is never being rendered and I think this has to do with your selector. It looks to me that you forgot to return your computed state.

```
export const selectAllPokemon = (state) => {
    Object.values(state.entities.pokemon);
};
// will return undefined
```

For returning your state you have two options:

**Explicit return**

```
 export const selectAllPokemon = (state) => {
   return Object.values(state.entities.pokemon);
};
```

**Implicit return**

```
 export const selectAllPokemon = (state) => (
   Object.values(state.entities.pokemon);
 );
```

I refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@bunlong/arrow-functions-return-rules-in-javascript-b63ed5f25994) or look at the examples I created in [playground](https://playcode.io/677123/) to get a better unstanding of implicit and explicit return in arrow functions.